# MongoDB is not working...: [js] Error: couldn't connect to server

Tags: mongodb

It was installed through Brew. The 'brew' service list says it works. However, if I run 'mongo', I get an error.

```
2020-03-08T13:33:52.076+0900 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-03-08T13:33:52.077+0900 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2020-03-08T13:33:52.077+0900 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 683
2020-03-08T13:33:52.077+0900 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure

leeyujeong@iyujeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % brew services list
Name              Status  User       Plist
mongodb-community started leeyujeong /Users/leeyujeong/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
leeyujeong@iyujeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % 
leeyujeong@iyujeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-08T13:35:02.579+0900 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-08T13:35:02.584+0900 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-08T13:35:02.584+0900 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
leeyujeong@iyujeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ %
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace as text and not as an image.

Comment: Hey, try to run the command without the --dbpath and copy/paste the output here please

Comment: I tried. Is this the right way to upload command?

Comment: This is why it didn't start: `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied`, try removing that file and restarting